# how to enable Direct Database Access while creating database in godaddy mysql?

Tags: shared-hosting

I want to connect to the mysql database hosted on Godaddy from my localhost. When i searching for the solution on Godaddy the supporting team says that I have to enable direct database access. But i can't found how it can be enabled.

Comment: how do you want to connect ? what language ? you just need a connection string.

Comment: I want to connect from C# windows application. I need a connection string for that and the the database support direct database access.

Comment: as far as i know you just need to give the user you create or assign to the database the the right privileges. then it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GoDaddy actually has a documentation about this. However, as stated, you can't enable Direct Database Access once the database is already created:

> You must enable Direct Database Access when setting it up — you cannot enable it later.

As you stated the database is already hosted at GoDaddy, I would advise:

1. Export the database (possibly using the database backup method, a .sql file should be downloaded)
2. Create a new database (enabling Direct Database Access)
3. Import the .sql file previously created

You will have to change your website's configuration in order to use the newly created database.

You can find the entire Help resource here: [Connect remotely to databases](https://ca.godaddy.com/en/help/connect-remotely-to-databases-4978)

Comment: But when I create a database I can't found the option for enabling direct database access. In support they explain how to enable database access along with the screen cast. But i can't even see that screen. I am getting entirely different screen.

Comment: Web & Classic Hosting Help it is saying. i think its old and incorrect information for shared hosting

Comment: @Creator AFAIK, GoDaddy doesn't keep old docs up, so it should be the right version.

Comment: i have a shared hosting server also and there is no option you can select when you create a database. you just give a name and it will get created. then you need to assign a user and give it privileges

Comment: @JINOSHAJI There is also [this help doc](https://ca.godaddy.com/en/help/create-mysql-or-ms-sql-databases-36) that explains how to create a new database with Direct Database Access. It states that you should contact support if you can't see the _Additional Options_ button.

Comment: Do you both use the free web hosting provided by GoDaddy? It also states, in that case, that you can't access to Direct Database Access (which, only to clarify for @Creator 's question on the original question, allows a connection through some normally protected ports to the database)

Comment: most likely he needs to add his ip  to the Remote MySQL® option you have in the control panel.https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Remote%20MySQL

Comment: That would be the way to go if @JINOSHAJI had access to a _straight_ cPanel, which I highly doubt. In my experience, GoDaddy hosting either doesn't provide a cPanel access or allow a limited access in order to force you to go through their regular channels (i.e. their own interfaces for database creation).

Answer (score 0):

go to remote MySQL from cpanel and add access host as " %.%.%.%" ( % is wildcard not safe but works fine :D)

Answer (score 0):

I just completed this.

Go To cPanel for the host of your database on GoDaddy

Select the app Remote MySQL

In the section Add Access Host

Enter the IP address of the machine which you would like to use to connect to the Host server.

Enter some description in the Comment section so you can identify the machine.

Push the 'Add Host' button and a new IP address will be added to the bottom in the Manage Access Host section.

You are now able to log in remotely from that IP address using the user name and password for the selected database.